# C# couldn't get class property value from lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm making a CRUD Service for my web API with ASP.NET Core 5 and Entity Framework Core. I'm trying to make a method, that gets one user from database by some of its values, which are chosen using lambda expression. The problem is that I can't get value of the property of the class with which I'm comparing the value of the user model.

The method code is:

```
public async Task<UserModel> FindOne(Expression<Func<UserModel, bool>> predicate)
{
    var candidates = await _context.Users.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    var user = candidates.First();
    return user;
}
```

Here is how I call the `FindOne` method:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserLoginResponseModel>> RegisterUser(UserRegisterRequestModel requestModel)
{
    var model = new UserModel(requestModel);
    var email = model.Email;

    var candidate = await _service.FindOne(u => u.Email == email);
            
    if (candidate is not null)
    {
        return BadRequest($"User with email {model.Email} is already registered");
    }

    // continuation of the code

}
```

I debugged my program and the value of `model.Email` in the `predicate` lambda expression is:

`value(.Constant<API.Controllers.UserController+<>c__DisplayClass4_0>(API.Controllers.UserController+<>c__DisplayClass4_0).model).Email`

But if I hard-code the value of `model.Email`, everything will work.

Entity Framework Core version: `5.0.12`

I don't know how to fix it. It would be really good if someone can help me.

Comment: Should work without any additional manipulations. Probably you are using this method in other lambda expression.  So, better show usage. Anyway, why `FirstAsync` do not work for you?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv This is the only use of the method. ```[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserLoginResponseModel>> RegisterUser(UserRegisterRequestModel requestModel)
{
   var model = new UserModel(requestModel);

   var candidate = await _service.FindOne(u => u.Email == model.Email);
            
   *continuation of the code*
}```

Comment: I also tried to use `FirstAsync()`, but it also throws `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements`.

Comment: The debugger can be tricky with EF and Linq. Try extracting the string value with `string email = model.Email` and using `u => u.Email == email`. I'm guessing the email does not exist exactly in the database (it may be case sensitive or have hidden whitespace).

Comment: @DStanley No, your idea didn't help. I use the method to check if user with some email is already exist. So method returns `null` or `the user, that has been found.`

Comment: So use `FirstOrDefault`, it is correct exception, when no records in sequence.

Comment: `First` will throw an error if no records exist. Use `FirstOrDefault` (the "default" is null for obejects) and check for a null result. Or use `Any()` if you just want to check existence and don't need the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I had to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` instead of `FirstAsync()`:

```
public async Task<UserModel> FindOne(Expression<Func<UserModel, bool>> predicate)
{

    var user = await _context.Users.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return user;

}
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.